# Is it possible to set visible and color for all 12 edges(spines) of the figure (cube) in matplotlib?

Tags: 3d

In 2d, matplotlib plots all 4 edges(spines) of a figure.

[image]

In 3d, matplotlib plots 9 out of 12 edges of a cube.

[image]

Is it possible to set visible and color for all 12 edges(spines) of a cube in 3d?

I tried `ax.xaxis._axinfo['juggled'] = (2,0,1)` and found that is something live move instead of setting visible or color.

I also tried `ax.collections`, didn't work either.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib's 3d rendering settings are not yet complete (it's meant to be a 2d renderer program). I don't think at this stage it has this option without big hacks to the code locally (i.e. done by yourself). Mathematica offers this setting naturally.